# flutter how to update condition

Tags: flutter

I am working on flutter code  and my target if string ultra1_app="off"  then car text appear ,else when ultra1_app="on" image show.

my code :

```
var ultra1_app;
if(ultra1_app =="on")...[
                         Image.asset('assets/image/car_slot.PNG',), ]
                    else...[
                                Text(
                                    'A2', /// must in it string of car
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 18)
                                     ),
                             ],`
```

My problem that the  second condition ( i.e. the else condition ) always apply in case ultra1_app is on or off.
So pleas your advice how i can update   the status  of the ultra1_app to show the image when ultra1_app="on" and car text when ultra1_app="off".

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
bool ultra1_app =true;

//lets say the contents are within Column widget

return Column(
  children:[
   (ultra1_app)?  
     Image.asset('assets/image/car_slot.PNG')
 :Text(
        'A2', /// must in it string of car
         style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 18)
      ),
   ],
);
```

Lets consider that you have a `FloatingActionButton` to update the state of the boolean.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              ultra1_app = !ultra1_app;
            });
          },
        ),
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem was not solved, that is, nothing changed, knowing that I used the code